# how do I show more than 5 featured products on homepage in magento 1.7?

Tags: magento

I've researched a ton, but I'm not finding a solution that's working for me.

I'm trying to show more than the default product count of 5 items in my Featured Products section on my homepage.

I've got 10 items currently set as "new", but only 5 will show up.

Any tips on how to do this without a core code change?

http://saks-jewelers.com

(ignore the slider at the bottom that I'm working on)

**Edited to explain more how I'm currently displaying them**

I've listed them using a template phtml file that I created, then added a static block to call this on my hp:

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="featured-products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
            <li >
            <div class="drop-shadow curved curved-hz-2">
                <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135) ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
        <button type="button" title="View Product" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span>View Product</span></span></button>
        </div>
            </li></a>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the static block code:

```
<div id="featured-products-container">
  <div class="featured-products-heading"><strong>Featured Products</strong></div>
  <div class="featured-products-heading-line"></div>
    <div id="featured-products-grid">
        {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/featured-products.phtml"}}
    </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should point out that I don't want to create a separate category to call these products from. I want to rely on the "set NewFrom" and "NewTo" dates for an item so that they can be scheduled ahead of time, etc.

Comment: what do you actually use for displaying those featured products? seems like a custom extension and you didn't provide any info about that.

Comment: No, no custom extension, just created a new .phtml file "featured-products.phtml" that calls the items (grabbed from someone's example I found a while back). and then I just created a new static-block to call this template file and then added this static block to my homepage.

Comment: great, what did you actually put in that `featured-products.phtml`?

Comment: ok, edited my question to include the phtml code. lemme know if you need to see my static block code

Comment: great, now `echo get_class( $this);` and would be nice to see the code you used to put that block in the homepage (probably something like `{{block... `), and what's the code for that `getCollection`.

Comment: ok, added the static block code for you.

Comment: the get_class ( $this) = Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New - not sure about the getCollection, as I borrowed this code, and php isn't my thing, I'm a html/css guy.

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Comment: your subject says 5 featured products.your further post says new products.So what are you planning to display on home page featured products or new products.

Comment: I'm labeling them as "Featured" but they're ones set as "new" within Magento's item properties, as explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its for new products and not for featured products( as you will have to use some extension for featured products and you hav enot stated any)
You need to change the line in `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\New.php`

```
$products->setOrder(’news_from_date’)->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
```

change to

```
$products->setOrder(’news_from_date’)->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(1);
```

This is just a reference code. You should not change any core files so you need to create your module and override block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`

Use this in your .phtml  as first line of code

`$this->setProductsCount(10);`

Comment: my new.php file doesn't contain this line anywhere (vers 1.7 ?) but thanks

Comment: const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 5; change this to  const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;  this is defined in  \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\New.php  This is not the accepted way but will be a way out for a quick fix

Comment: Also there is  public function setProductsCount($count). So in your .phtml try this($this->setProductsCount(10)) before this line of code <?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thanks! - So, I followed your most recent suggestion, of putting it in my phtml file and then using the products_count="10" line in my {{block ...}} within my static block where I call my phtml file, and that worked great - no need to hack at new.php. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you did `echo count($_products)` you would probably find that it is always 5. That is because the block is determining what collection is loaded. Open the block which contains the `$this->getProductCollection()` function and follow the code. The collection will be limited there somewhere probably by a call to a backend setting via Mage::getStoreConfig.
I hope this helps!

Comment: (new to php), so would that just be the same block I identify before "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New" ? Can I change the count without hacking at the core block, tho? I really want this to be a simple change that allows for easy core updating later on....

Comment: one thread I found had people trying to change this count by an XML layout update, but I couldn't get it to work... maybe I was doing it wrong however?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` to display your new products... All good. Let's take a look at the block class definition:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_productsCount = null;

    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 5;
```

that `const` definition should catch you attention, because that's the reason for displaying only 5 products.
In `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New::_beforeToHtml()` function the collection is limited to a certain number:

`[...]->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())[...]`

```
public function getProductsCount()
{
    if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
        $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
    }
    return $this->_productsCount;
}
```

The "magic" thing (homework: dig into Magento and find out why) is that `_productCount` can also be passed from the template:

```
{{block products_count="2" type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/featured-products.phtml"}}
```

which will display only 2 products.

Comment: This works to limit my display down to 2, but if I use "products_count="10", it still only shows 5...?

Comment: If I change the const to be defined as "10" in new.php then it works, of course, but I shouldn't mess with this file as it'll just get overwritten when I update magento down the road, no? (forgive me, I'm very much a novice when it comes to php and magento core files).