# List More than 5 new products in Magento 1.9.1.1 home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to display more than 5 (exact 10) new product on Static CMS home page on a Magento CE 1.9.1.1 installation with Magento default sample data . I already marked more than 10 product as new items.

To get it, I made a child theme for Magento RWD theme and in its local.xml file, I put the below code snippet.

```
 <layout version="0.1.0">

        <cms_index_index translate="label">
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new_list.phtml" after="cms_page">
                <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>
                <action method="setProductsCount"><count>10</count></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </cms_index_index>

    </layout>
```

But Magento only display 5 new products on home page. If I reduce the product count less than 5 (`<action method="setProductsCount"><count>3</count></action>`), the above code works and Magento output 3 products as New Items.

But for more than 5 items, `setProductsCount` fails.

I searched different pages & none of the solutions works for me. There is a same question here for Magento 1.7.

[how do I show more than 5 featured products on homepage in magento 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300036/how-do-i-show-more-than-5-featured-products-on-homepage-in-magento-1-7)

How Magento limit this count? In the above page, I realize that we are going to load the block class, `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php` file. In that file, there is default count variable declaration.

```
 const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;
```

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

We know that this block selected products which are set *Set Product as New from Date*.
**Magento Admin > Catalog > Manage Products >** choose your products you want to show > **Product as New from Date**. You try to clear all Magento Cache and Re-index your database.

We also see a widget new products block in content of Homepage CMS. We can use this Widget:

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

If you want to change products per row, you will change *product_count* value.

Actually, your issue is weird, the same issue is resolved here: [Magento limit the number of products shown with in the new products block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050587/magento-limit-the-number-of-products-shown-with-in-the-new-products-block)

You should test with a fresh new Magento. And, then try to figure out what reason causes this issue, can be custom code lines or an extension.

**Update:** may caused by Css style.